# Minikube. Как разрешать доступ из контейнера к локальной базе данных?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

Проблема состоит в том, что при запуске приложения в контейнере minikube нет доступа к локальной базе данных mySql.
Я использую minikube с драйвером hyper-v. Я понимаю что в контейнере существует свой localhost. 
Есть-ли какие варианты подключения к localhost вне minikube, чтобы не создавать отдельный контейнер с mySql сервером внутри minikube?

Comment: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/accessing-host-resources/

Comment: @ExplodingKitten route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print $2 }' - я тут не силен, но такая команда(без знака "/") у меня работает - возвращает ip 172.18.4.209. При проверке telnet: telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.18.4.209): Connection timed out. Не знаю, связано-ли это с драйвером, но инструкция не для hyper-v

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Ну я по инструкции из ссылки делал (проверял из minikube ssh). По поводу привязки - это запись bind-address = 127.0.0.1? На windows10 в файле my.ini этой записи нет, при добавлении сервер не стартует.